# MongoDB compare array_A with documents $match array_B, and return Array_C (array_A less array_B)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregate

I am trying to find an array_C, which contains only items in array_A that do not appear in array_B. But I'm trying to use $match in aggregate to represent array_B.

Example:

```
array_A = [1, 2, 3]
array_B = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
array_C = [1, 3]
```

And doing this using Model.aggregate() using $match criteria.

Here is how I *think* the code should work:

```
Model.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            "u_oid": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.u_oid),
            "t_oid": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.t_oid)              
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : { "array_C" : {"$filter": { "input": array_A, "$cond": {"$not": { "$in": "$match"} }}}}

    }]
).exec((err, doc) => {
    console.log("The doc is: "+JSON.stringify(doc))
})
```

In this case, I'm using `"$match"` to represent `array_B`.

The console log returns: `undefined`.

---

*edit*

**Here is a more detailed example of the desired output:**

Note: each array is made up of `ObjectIds`:

```
array_A = ["5f522bc55dd8993e58283526","5f522ab45dd8993e58283521","5f522ba65dd8993e58283525","5f522a5e5dd8993e5828351f"]    

array_B = ["5f522bc55dd8993e58283526","5f522ab45dd8993e58283521"]

array_C = ["5f522ba65dd8993e58283525","5f522a5e5dd8993e5828351f"]
```

array_A comes from another API. I am trying to compare it to a different doc set, and find which ones don't have a match.

Thanks for comments.

Comment: Would [$setlsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) and [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) work for you?

Comment: `$match` is an operator, you cannot use it in condition

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - How can I capture that `$match` set as an array for the `$project`?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. The output of each stage (e.g. a `$match` stage) is the input for the next stage. You an use `$$ROOT` to access entire document but I don't think that is what you are looking for. Please provide a valid sample for input and desired output. Your question does not show any MongoDB data, just three variables.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I added more details to the question

Comment: These are not more details - again provide valid Mongo documents, not variables - this would be Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one?

```
{"$project": {array_C: { $setDifference: [ "$array_A", "$array_B" ] } }}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pJwc2Dj-uFC)

Comment: That approach works, but if you look at my code I’m struggling to define array_B in the query.